# Verify whether 'C:\Program Files\' is writable

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, lua, command-prompt

I have a situation where the user can configure the target location of some files (being downloaded and installed for use with the application). There are two configured locations, a system location and a user location. The application is a (Lua based) command line tool.

Before installing I check the location being writable by writing a temporary file and deleting it again. If this fails, I restart the same command with elevated priviledges, which allows installation by admins, but not regular users.

**Problem**: The system location default is located inside `C:\Program Files\`, which is protected (not a problem) and redirected (this is the problem) to the `C:\Users\<name>\AppData\VirtualStore\Program Files\...` directory.
Because of this redirection the test succeeds, stuff is being installed without elevated priviledges. And hence ends up in the `VirtualStore`, instead of getting an error that the user doesn't have the required priviledges.

**Question**: So how can I test actual `C:\Program Files\` being writable, without invoking redirection to the VirtualStore?

Comment: Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection.

Comment: @Sneftel That is for 64/32 bit compatibility. Not for UAC related as my problem is. And then also; I only have access to commandline commands or Lua scripting. Not to any Windows API functions.

Comment: Won't be checking if you Admin rights be enough?

Comment: @npocmaka No, as the location is configurable, so if it is in a location that doesn't require admin priviledges, it should just work without unnecessarily requesting admin priviledges.

Comment: I don't know the details, but UAC virtual store redirection only occurs for some executables, so you might be able to make your program immune to it by putting the appropriate flags in the manifest.

Comment: @Harry You probably are right, but I have no control over the executable as it is a Lua script, executing OS commands. The Lua interpreter is already present on the system.

Answer (score 1):

I tried some tricks to see what command are redirected and which not.
Initially I tried copying the temp file to a second temp file in the same location using the os `copy` command, but both reading the source and writing the destination where redirected in that case.

This Lua code gave the final verdict;

```
function is_writable(file)
   assert(file)
   file = dir.normalize(file)
   local result
   local tmpname = 'tmptestwritable.deleteme'
   if fs.is_dir(file) then
      local file2 = dir.path(file, tmpname)
      local fh = io.open(file2, 'wb')
      result = fh ~= nil
      if fh then fh:close() end
      if result then
         -- the above test might give a false positive when writing to
         -- c:\program files\ because of VirtualStore redirection on Vista and up
         -- So get a directory listing and check whether it's really there
         local pipe = io.popen("dir "..fs.Q(file))
         local dir_list = pipe:read("*a")
         pipe:close()
         result = (nil ~= string.find(dir_list, tmpname, 1, true))
      end
      os.remove(file2)
   else
      local fh = io.open(file, 'r+b')
      result = fh ~= nil
      if fh then fh:close() end
   end
   return result
end
```

After the regular 'writing a test file', it does a `dir` command on the target folder, which simply returns the contents without redirection, then it searches this content for the temporary name used.

thanks for your effort!

Comment: +1.  As an optimization, since `cmd.exe` is not redirecting, it ought to be possible to use something like `io.popen("if exist ...` rather than searching the output, or even to use `io.popen` to perform the attempt to write the file in the first place.

Comment: @Harry just tested it, and you are right. "IF EXIST" is used extensively, but just not hit in this part of the application, hence I concluded that it didn't work. My bad, that indeed is a simplification.

Answer (score 0):

```
del /q /f "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files\redirectionTest" >nul 2>&1
echo test>"%ProgramFiles%\redirectionTest"
if exist "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files\redirectionTest" (
  echo redirected
) else (
  echo not redirected
)
```

??

or may be just:

```
echo test>"%ProgramFiles%\redirectionTest"
if exist "%ProgramFiles%\redirectionTest" echo not redirected
```

is `IF EXIST` also redirected?

Comment: Yes, `If EXIST` is also redirected, we use it extensively. Even the GNU `ls.exe` command (bundled with our app) lists the contents of the directory as the combined contents of the real and virtual locations. So even though it is a problem now, I think MS did a good job in implementing it very transparent.

Comment: At least deleting the temp file in `VirtualStore` and creating it in `ProgramFiles` and then check again in `VirtualStore` should work..

Comment: I didn't test it, as my current solution works. The reason I'm hesitant of accessing the VirtualStore directly is that I'm not sure whether Program Files is the only redirect location or whether there are more. My current solution, capturing the `dir` command output and verify, will work on every location.

Comment: @Tieske: AFAIK, no native `cmd.exe` functions are redirected, and this should include `if exist`; perhaps you were talking about Lua's equivalent function?

Comment: My above comment that `IF EXIST` is also redirected is wrong. It is not. Thanks to @Harry for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

does this work?

```
@echo off
2>nul (
(call ) >>"C:\Program Files\file"
) && (
   rem we have access
   rem do stuff
   exit /b
)
rem we dont have access
rem do stuff
```

if not, im afraid i dont understand your problem, so please explain what didnt work about it.

Comment: But isn't the problem that it will redirect the data to virtualstore and this operation never fails?

Comment: i don't know, it worked when i tested it, but maybe that's cause i use an admin account